# PHP - let client read image from another sever

Tags: php, server, load-balancing

Lets say the client types:

```
serverA.com/image.php?bla.jpg
```

now on

```
serverA.com/image.php?bla.jpg
```

I want to send the image from

```
serverB.com/image/bla.jpg
```

directly to the client without sending the image from serverB to serverA and then to client first.

Looking at 9gag, the clients always requesting the images from the same server which is `img-9gag-fun.9cache.com`

and I don't think that all the xxx of terrabytes are stored on this one server.

`img-9gag-fun.9cache.com` is probably only the place where all the balancing happens?

I know I could just redirect the client to the image but then the url changes which is not what is happening on 9gag, the url always stays the same.

Comment: 9cache.com is a CDN. It caches the files from the original server so it can respond more quickly to clients.

Comment: If it runs out of space, it can evict some files, it will download them again the next time they're needed.

Comment: It's still unthinkable that this one server delievers content to the millions clients

Comment: It's not one server.

Comment: Do you think `www.google.com` is one server?

Comment: This is why I am asking this question. Google is using dns balancing, I'm curious if that's also the case for img-9gag-fun.9cache.com or if the content is served by some kind of redirect without changing the url

Comment: The name "9cache.com" implies that it's a caching server. This is similar to CloudFlare.

Comment: I'm sure they're using DNS-based load balancing, too.

Comment: In fact, it looks like they're using CloudFlare. img-9gag-fun.9cache.com is an alias for docollp554xot.cloudfront.net.

Comment: Ok but then how does cloudfront spread all the content using only one url. Ok it's probably dns load balancing but still, how does the load balancer know on which ip the requested image is :D I can't find proper explanations/tutorials about all that

Comment: Read about CDNs: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/

Answer (score 0):

Send the client a redirect:

```
header("Location: http://serverB.com/image/{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}");
```

Comment: This is a normal redirect, url changes

Comment: You asked how to do it without downloading the file to your server first, this is how you do it.

Comment: That's not how 9cache.com works, they DO download the file to their server.

Comment: But at the end I wrote: "I know I could just redirect the client to the image but then the url changes which is not what is happening on 9gag, the url always stays the same."

Comment: You want to tell me img-9gag-fun.9cache.com downloads the images first and then sends it to the millions clients? Is img-9gag-fun.9cache.com running on a 999 terabyte bandwidth machine with 10000 cpus and 99 terabyte RAM? :D

Comment: It's using CloudFlare. They have a network of hundreds or thousands of servers all around the world.